# Bundling Typescript in ASP.NET Core

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, configuration, bundle

I recently updated an ASP.NET Core/React project to use TypeScript. However I've noticed that in order to get the TypeScript to compile I need to put the imports at the top of the file. When the bundler combines these files the imports do not get removed and this leads to an `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module` error. The jsx that comes out the other end is fine besides the imports. Is there a way to make the default bundler handle these imports?

bundleconfig.json

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/vehicles.jsx",
    "inputFiles": 
     [
       "built/Components/General/VehiclePanel.jsx",
       "built/Components/Vehicles/VehiclePage.jsx"
     ],
     "minify": 
     {
       "enabled": false,
       "renameLocals": false
     },
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/editVehicle.jsx",
    "inputFiles": 
     [
       "built/Components/General/Job.jsx",
       "built/Components/General/History.jsx",
       "built/Components/General/EditVehiclePanel.jsx",
       "built/Components/Vehicles/EditVehiclePage.jsx"
     ],
     "minify": 
     {
       "enabled": false,
       "renameLocals": false
     },
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/editService.jsx",
    "inputFiles": 
     [
       "built/Components/General/Job.jsx",
       "built/Components/General/History.jsx",
       "built/Components/General/ServicePanel.jsx",
       "built/Components/Services/ServicePage.jsx"
     ],
     "minify": 
     {
       "enabled": false,
       "renameLocals": false
     },
  },
]
```

An example of a component with an import statement

```
// Name History.tsx
// Author: Redacted
// CreatedDate: 24/02/2020
// ModifiedDate: 29/02/2020
// Description: History panel
import { Component } from 'react';
import { IHistory } from "../../Interfaces/Interfaces";

interface HistoryProps {
    history: IHistory;
}

export class History extends Component<HistoryProps> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="box">
                    <div className="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 className="box-title">{this.props.history.title}</h3><div className="box-tools pull-right">{this.props.history.createdDateTime}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="box-body">
                        {this.props.history.description.split("\n").map(function (history, i) { return <p key={"h" + i}>{history}</p> })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I just noticed the compiled component still has the `export` statement in front of it. This makes me think it might have something to do with how my typescript is being compiled. I have added my tsconfig.json in case it's relevant.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "es2016", "dom" ],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./Scripts/Components/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./Scripts/Interfaces/*"
  ]
}
```

2nd EDIT: after adding `"module": "none"` to `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json the import and export statements were removed. Unfortunatly this removed the effect of a previous change I had made. I set `"moduleResolution": "Node"` in `compilerOptions` to address this being added to the top of all files.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Comment: The tsconfig as shown would produce commonjs output (`module.exports` and `require("m")`).  Is that what you're getting?

Comment: Also, note that bundle config file and the tools that use it will be an adequate for a module based web application with more than a handful of files to it. You need to look into more robust tooling like Webpack or SystemJS.  note that this would likewise be the case if you are not using TypeScript

Comment: I get `const react_1 = require("react");` at the top of each output file and `exports.ComponentNameHere = ComponentNameHere;` at the bottom.
but when I added `"module": "none"` to the config it seems to have overridden a previous change and these two lines came back.
`"use strict"; Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`

Comment: When you use import statements, the default is commonjs.

Comment: Damn I was hoping to use the default one but I'll probably just install webpack. Cheers

Comment: `module: None`  is not a default module format. If you use modules, the compiler has to translate them in some way

Comment: so I should target CommonJS?

Comment: if you're using webpack you should set module to esnext. This is because webpack will compile the Imports that typescript leaves unchanged. Webpack can create a bundle from, common JS but it is less efficient

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue where this was added to the top of every file.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

I had to move the export to the top of the file.

I changed it from this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IVehicle } from "../../Interfaces/Interfaces";

export class VehiclePanel extends React.Component<IVehicle> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
```

to this

```
export = VehiclePanel;
import * as React from 'react';
import { IVehicle } from "../../Interfaces/Interfaces";

class VehiclePanel extends React.Component<IVehicle> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
```